# Unity Sprites not sliced correctly

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, slice

[image: Perfectly sliced]

So I made a spride sheet for a button animation, which Unity shows me in the spriteeditor as perfectly sliced, up to the individual pixel, But once I test them they are cut off like this:

[image: Not correct]

Comment: what size(resolution) is the original tilesheet?

Answer (score 0):

The two images you uploaded are not the same, the grids of the second image greater this we react the first image.

If you want to upload the image.png your button that try to check more precisely what can this place. Try also manually drag the boundary line the edges by clicking on them.

Answer (score 0):

If the slice is not using correctly maybe because they are close to each other. You can manually slice them

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. How I solved is to produce my sprite as a grid with rows and columns instead of a single line. Then sliced it by rows and columns. Single line slicing causes distorted portions of sprite animation.

It slices more accurate sprites with columns instead of rows.